# LocalDB AttachDbFilename connsectionString absolute path works but relative does not

Tags: asp.net-core

In my appsettings json file I have:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyDBConnectionString": "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=.\\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True",
}
```

At runtime this throws:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .\TestHistoryDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

If I change it to absolute path:

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\\MyProject\\TestData\\MyDB.mdf
```

It works....
How can I fix it?

Let me note that I even tried manually putting the .mdf file in the output directory of the project, for the relative path to work.. yet it didnt.

Comment: Based on this docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string I think you should `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf`

Comment: I tried this, but doesnt work.. seems that it only applies for regular framework, not .net core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the right AttachDbFilename relative path in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058684/how-to-set-the-right-attachdbfilename-relative-path-in-asp-net-core)