# Connect to a SQL Server database without a set file path

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am attempting to connect to a local SQL Server database in C#.

I am currently using the following connection string:

```
connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\majorWork\majorWork\gameStats.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

However, I do not want to use a hardcoded file path, as I wish to be able to use the application across multiple computers, where the file path will be different. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You should store the file to a specific folder which you can locate using path relative to the application path. For example you create a folder `Database` where the application is running. Then you can use relative path as `AttachedDbFileName = .\Database\gameStats.mdf`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058684/how-to-set-the-right-attachdbfilename-relative-path-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Er, you can modify the connection string before you use it to create a connection.. "hardcode" a placeholder into it and replace the placeholder with the actual location of the db for the machine the program runs on

Comment: You should really put the database on the **server** - for which SQL Server is built - and then reference that server by its server name and let SQL Server handles all the file-related details.

Comment: Never use AttachedDbFileName when a database is attached to a SQL Server.  It is not needed.  Just remove the  AttachedDbFileName it is not needed.  Just use "Data Source" with server name and instance that you see on the login windows of SQL Server Management Studio.  The database owns the mdf file and you do not have permission to read the file especially when mdf is on a remote machine.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how do I go about reloacting the file, as when I attempt to copy it across I get the error: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .\database\gameStats.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

Comment: How are you relocating the file? If you have found the solution for the problem yo mentioned in this question... please ask different question for the other problem you are facing... it would be seen by wider audience and have better chances of being solved..

Answer (score 1):

Best way is set this connection in Web.Config file.

```
<Database>
  <ConnectionString name="connection">Server=servername; Initial Catalog=dbname; Persist Security Info=False; User ID=username; Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=False; Connection Timeout=30;;</ConnectionString>
</Database>
```

Then add Add System.Configuration as a reference.

in C# you can call this

```
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
```

After that you can create new connection instance by passing this to

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring)
```

Answer (score 0):

If u install SQL server express using the default instance, then you can connect using . as your server name anyone can use it with default instance as well.
1.then in visual studio, click on solution explorer
2. Connect database, follow the instruction for SQL server
3. When it gets to server name use . to connect and choose your database name which you have created already in ms SQl, then test your connection
4. After it successful, u can now click on the database name showing under solution explorer,
5.after u click the database name, at the button right corner, there will be a connection string, copy it and use
This will be declared publicly or globally

```
Sqlconnection con = new sqlconnection("paste the connection string");
```

And to use

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("insert into......",con);
Con.open ();
Cmd.executenonquery();
Con.close();
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution.  Do not try.   Why uninstall the SQL Server.  It make absolutely no sense.

Comment: No one is suggesting him to install, that how I use it and it working even for local host

Comment: He already has it installed.  You are suggesting for him to uninstall.  OP does not want to user LocalDb .See my comment in posting.

Comment: I simply said if he had installed the server using the default instance, not like he should uninstall and install again, OK have heard you, if u think that was what I meant, so be it