# how to set connectionString for connect Database inside App_Data in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string, asp.net5, app-data

Old Project
**Web.config**

Following **ConnectionString** use for **App_Data**  Database Connection

```
  <add name="MaContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;

 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MaintenanceDB.mdf;Integrated 
 Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now I am using **Asp.net Core** With   **.NET 5**

**appsettings.json**

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {

  "BCAContext": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;   AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MaintenanceDB.mdf;

  Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
  }
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: It search for the mdf file in the bin/debug/net5.0 folder. Place it there

Comment: but My database inside App_data so any thing need to change to access project app_data same i used in asp.net framework old version

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058684/how-to-set-the-right-attachdbfilename-relative-path-in-asp-net-core

Comment: now error is No service for type 'BCA_New_System.Models.BCAContext' has been registered.'